# Excel Macro with an Alpha Sort and Row Expansion

Tags: excel, vba

I am somewhat familiar with excel macros (not hugely familiar because this may seem like an obvious code to some) and I was given the task to organize a list. I have to organize this list weekly, therefore I don't want to have to manually alpha sort every week and am trying to develop a macro that could so it for me.

The requirements would be that I can alpha sort by column and have that sort expand to the rest of the column so that the rows don't get misaligned. Any suggests?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data?  That would help us answer your question better.

Comment: I can't provide an example due to the nature in the information. But essentially it's 5 columns with an unknown finite amount of rows. I have to alpha sort by the different columns, but the row has to stay in tack.

Comment: are the columns all connected within the sheet?

Comment: Yes all the columns are connected within the sheet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in column's A:E, you can enter the following code on the sheet you're wanting to sort object (assuming you want column a sorted)

```
Sub sortme()
Columns("A:E").sort key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

If you are entering it in a module, you will need to reference the sheet first like this

```
Sub sortme()
Sheets("MySheet").Columns("A:E").sort key1:=Range("A1"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: Plese note - this is also assuming you have headers for your data.  If there are no headers you will need to remove the Header:=xlYes

Comment: Thank you so much, I will let you know if this works!

Comment: I ran into an error "Runtime error '1004'" can you identify where that would go wrong?

Comment: which code snippet did you use and where are you running the code?